# ASP.NET MVC 2 controller-url problems

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am still very new to the MVC framework, but I managed to create a controller that reads from a database and writes JSON to an url;

`host.com/Controllername?minValue=something&maxValue=something`

However when I move the site to a subfolder;

`host.com/mvc/`

it doesn't seem to be able to call the controller from there when I do it like this;

`host.com/mvc/Controllername?minValue=something&maxValue=something`

Did I forget to do something somewhere to make this url call valid from that subfolder?
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are specifying the controller name while in the second case you are not. You could setup a default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Controllername",
        action = "ActionName",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Once this default route points to the controller and action both urls should work:

```
host.com/?minValue=something&maxValue=something
host.com/mvc/?minValue=something&maxValue=something
```